# Annotate a count of a related field

Tags: django, django-models

*django: 1.5.5*

I need to order domains by the number of rentals.

**models:**

```
class Rental(models.Model):
    ...

class Domain(models.Model):
    ...


class RentalExtraBase(models.Model):
    rental = models.ForeignKey(Rental, unique=True, related_name='extras')

    class Meta:
       abstract = True


class RentalExtra(RentalExtraBase):
    domain = models.ForeignKey(Domain)
```

**query:**

```
from django.db.models import Count
Domain.objects.all().annotate(rentalextra_set_count=Count('rentalextra_set'))
```

however it's seems to be impossible using this field. I tried with a specific `related_name` without success.

**error:**

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'rentalextra_set' into field ... (list of the Domain fields without rentalextra or rentalextra_set)
```

Any idea?

Regard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just use the lower-case name of the related model, as you do when following a relationship backwards in a query:

```
Domain.objects.all().annotate(rentalextra_set_count=Count('rentalextra'))
```

Comment: Are you sure that code is the bit causing the error? I've just copied and pasted your models and run that command in the shell with no problems. Can you post your updated code and the full traceback?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Register my Domain model through django-ModelTranslation before the RentalExtra model breaks the mechanism to reverse relations. thx